# Does Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) library have rules for longitude/latitude coordinates?

Tags: coordinates, unicode

Does the [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) library](http://cldr.unicode.org) contain rules for formating longitude/latitude coordinates?

I am looking for information how coordinates should be formatted in each language/country.

Comment: Seems that your link is broken.